# Database application using SQL Server 2008 or any dbms

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm developing a database application using SQL Server 2008. Since I finished my project and I thought I should see it working on another PC or friend. There is a problem in the database server it wants to connect. I want my app connects to the SQL Server every time it runs on a PC of mine, or any other's without losing any data.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 installed. I want to use my app other pc without installing Microsft SQL Server.

Comment: Your "other PC" must either have SQL Server 2008 installed, too - or it needs to be on a network that can access a server that you've set up where SQL Server is running, and your database is deployed to.

Comment: can you share the connection string you are using to connect to the database server?

Comment: how if the other pc has not sql server 2008 installed, i want it without installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your database 'portable' you have a few options:

- Use a online database service, like [Microsoft Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/). You can have one central database which you can use with an internet connection;
- Save the database next to the application, something like 'embedded', you can use [LocalDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) for that. Make sure you copy the database file along with the application.

Comment: `LocalDB` is a version of SQL Server Express, and it's a separate install - it's not "embedded" in that you can just ship a few DLL's with your application - it needs to be installed separately, before using your software

Comment: its microsoft sql server 2008, not local db

Comment: @marc_s: No, but you can embed the database, since you don't need to register the database to the server, like in regular SQL Server installations. You indeed need to install SQL Express/LocalDB.

Comment: @cyuusuf178: Then use Azure. I doubt you really need SQL2008. Most of the time SQL Express/LocalDB will do.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: can local DB handle what Microsoft SQL Server handle

Comment: Most of it you will usually need is small development. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx.

Comment: @marc_s: dude how can i use LocalDB. i think i don't have any idea about. thnks friend

Comment: @cyuusuf178: Install SQL Server Express: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to run your application on another pc, one way is updating connectionString of DB.

Comment: i want it to be like any other software and handle many tables

Comment: In this case I am agree with @Patrick. If you want to share data between all installed applications you should use a central DB.(In this case you can have a local DB for each installed version and provide a mechanism for synching their data with central DB)

Comment: i don't understand what you mean 'central DB' exactly? please clear it and thanks

Comment: My point is something like client and server. you should design and implement your database in server (as Central DB) and for clients (which are installed versions of you app) design and implement a local database. Then you should provide a protocol for communication between clients and server (for synching purpose). Notice that if your app is standalone and do not share data with any other, you can use databases like SQLite and put DB inside your app.

Comment: thanks and i got it, but if i use localdb in my app , may it hold data like sql server or anything like table size something like that. if it is yes i should use localdb.